# Help with MySQL JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

Table A is a category table. Columns are `cid, catname`.

Table B is a relationship table. Columns are `cid, parent` (`parent` is another `cid`).

Here's where I am so far:

```
"SELECT c.cid, c.catname AS catname, r.parent AS parent FROM tableA AS c JOIN tableB AS r ON r.cid=c.cid";
```

I know I'll get 3 columns (2 from `tableA` and one from `tableB`) but I also want to get the `catname` value from the `parent` in `tableA` If I were to do a second query, it would look like this (assuming we put the result into a `$row` variable):

```
"SELECT catname FROM tableA WHERE cid='".$row['parent']."'";
```

That way I can display it as text.

What do I add, and where? Is there a second `JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join a table multiple times:

```
SELECT a.cid AS acid, a.catname AS aname,
       b.cid AS bcid, b.catname AS bname
FROM relationships AS r
     JOIN categories AS a ON (r.cid = a.cid)
     JOIN categories AS b ON (r.parent = b.cid)
```

Comment: thank you! I can't believe I actually understand how you did that. I must be learning something :)